# Getting values from other column telerik Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

In asp.net mvc5 i have this [telerik grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-row)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KerberosTest.Models.Bench>()
        .Name("grid")

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.name).Title("Bench").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains"))).Width(150);
        //columns.Bound(p => p.seatsCount).Title("Total Seats");
        //columns.Bound(p => p.bookedSeats).Title("Booked Seats");

        columns.Bound(p => p.seatsCount).Title("Total Seats").Width(150).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("checkBench").Text("Check in").Click("ShowTimePopup")).Width(160).Title("Check in");


    })
```

i want to know if when i press the button and call ShowTimePopup, i can read the first column value (the one with p => p.name) of the same row as the button i clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty ease to get the current row's data if you use `grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowTimePopup()
    {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var rowData = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
        alert(rowData.name);
    }
</script>
```